# Using Fetch (tedious) to get email to/from

Tags: php, email

So I am trying to get Fetch (tedious: https://github.com/tedious/Fetch)set up and running on a local server and everything has been going swimmingly. I can get the body just fine by using: `$body = $message->getHtmlBody();` , but I am a bit confused on how to actually get the to/from. I thought I could get it simply by using: `$sentFrom = $message->getAddresses('from')`, but I am not getting the right results. I looked in the Message.php file, and there is a function named getAddresses():

```
    /**
 * This function returns either an array of email addresses and names or, optionally, a string that can be used in
 * mail headers.
 *
 * @param  string            $type     Should be 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'from', 'sender', or 'reply-to'.
 * @param  bool              $asString
 * @return array|string|bool
 */
public function getAddresses($type, $asString = false)
{
    $type = ( $type == 'reply-to' ) ? 'replyTo' : $type;
    $addressTypes = array('to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'from', 'sender', 'replyTo');

    if (!in_array($type, $addressTypes) || !isset($this->$type) || count($this->$type) < 1)
        return false;

    if (!$asString) {
        if ($type == 'from')
            return $this->from[0];
        elseif ($type == 'sender')
            return $this->sender[0];

        return $this->$type;
    } else {
        $outputString = '';
        foreach ($this->$type as $address) {
            if (isset($set))
                $outputString .= ', ';
            if (!isset($set))
                $set = true;

            $outputString .= isset($address['name']) ?
                $address['name'] . ' <' . $address['address'] . '>'
                : $address['address'];
        }

        return $outputString;
    }
}
```

I have probably just made a dumb mistake, but I have no idea now. Any insight would be quite helpful.

So currently, I am just looping through the messages and outputing the message subject, from, to, and the body. For example:

```
$server = new Server('imap.myserver.com', 993);
$server->setAuthentication('test@domain.com', 'mypassword');

$messages = $server->getMessages();

$i = 0;
$output = "";

foreach($messages as $message) {
    $html = true;
    $subject = $message->getSubject(); //get the subject of the email
    $sentFrom = $message->getAddresses('from'); // who sent the email
    $sentTo = $message->getAddresses('to'); //who is the email to
    $body = $message->getHtmlBody();

    //construct the email with a wrapper for little nicer look
    $output .= "<div class=\"email\">";
    $output .= "<div class=\"header\">";
    $output .= "<p>{$subject}</p>";
    $output .= "<p>{$sentFrom}</p>";
    $output .= "<p>{$sentTo}</p>";
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "<div class=\"body\">";
    $output .= $body;
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</div>";
}

echo $output;
if (++$i = 10) break;
```

If everything is working correctly, when I refresh the page, the script connects to the email server, checks the emails, and gather the subject, to, from, and body of all the emails in the foreach. It also will output the emails to the screen. Unfortunately, the only 2 variables not really working are the $sentTo and $sentFrom. I guess I am just confused why I am not getting the addresses returned to me using `$sentTo = $message->getAddresses('to');` when the function in Message.php says:

```
 * @param  string    $type     Should be 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'from', 'sender', or 'reply-to'.
```

Comment: Can you share your own code and explain further what does not work and what should?

Answer (score 0):

So, after digging into it further, I have found the solution. It appears that once I added in:

```
$arrayedTo = print_r($sentTo);
$arrayedFrom = print_r($sentFrom);
```

I got the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => firstlast@mydomain.com
            [name] => My Name
        )

)

Array
(
    [address] => firstlast@sentfromdomain.com
    [name] => Name of Sender
)
```

Therefore, in my foreach loop I had to do the following to get the proper results. I guess I just overlooked the fact that it was returning an array.

```
Sent From Address: {$sentFrom['address']}
Sent To Address: {$sentTo[0]['address']}
```